# Responsive media queries IE

Tags: internet-explorer, media-queries

I have a responsive website on Wordpress which works well across all platforms apart from in the browser of IE.

To solve the responsive issue for IE i have used a plugin called respond.js which is great and brings in my media queries from my main stylesheet into IE.

My issue is that there are some elements missing or divs altered position in IE. Now i've heard that you can call in a seperate ie stylesheet for the browser but i am having some problems.

When on load you can see the tags:

`<!--[if lt IE]> <![endif]-->` in the actual website copy.

The ie stylesheet does load in as i tested with a different background colour but no media queries work within that stylesheet. When my browser goes smaller and width 100% i lose some important div's and i cant alter my original stylesheet as it's ok in other browsers.

I really hope this makes sense and below is the position of where my elements are in my header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri(); ?>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/media-queries.css"/>

<!--[if lt IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/ie.css"/>
<![endif]-->

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/js/respond.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/js/placeholder.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my ie link stylesheet to this:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/ie.css" type="text/css" />
<!![endif]-->
```

And works fine!